# Accessing session from the view

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an item in the session it stores the case Id the person is working on in that time to the sub views.

I want to access the session as follows.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="MISObjects" asp-route-id="@Context.Session.GetString("caseId")>
   Back To Case
</a>
```

I save the information into the session as such. But it doesnt work its just blank when it goes to the edit controller

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaseId", id.ToString());
```

Comment: Session keys in Asp.Net Core are case sensitive. And `"caseId" != "CaseId"`

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea for your view to rely explicitly on `Session`. Ideally,it should only rely on the view-model. In your Controller, you should fill up the desired property (in your view-model) from the data currently stored in `Session`

Comment: @haim770 its cause im passing it to a one to many that table has no knowledge of the master.

Comment: @haim770 SO Your saying even though its linked through entity framework i should have a field to store the case Id into the model and be able to go back to that case edit page using that value

Comment: @rogue39nin，In fact, using id as a field will be more stable than using session, which method to choose is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As @haim770 said, ***the key value stored in the session is case sensitive***.

You must ensure that the key value obtained is exactly the same as the set key value.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="MISObjects" asp-route-id="@Context.Session.GetString("CaseId")">
    Back To Case
</a>
```